Powershell get-service -Status property issue
Under powershell >= 5.1
I get:
PS C:\> get-service -Status Running
Get-Service: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Status'

But the property does exist anyway ?
PS C:\> get-service | Get-Member


Get-Service does not know -Status

Just because a command returns a property doesn't mean it's also a parameter.

Yes, you're right, my mistake... Thanks !

PowerShell is designed to handle problems like this through composition - if Get-Service returns objects with a Status property that you want to filter on, simply compose a new pipeline by adding the Where-Object cmdlet downstream:
Get-Service |Where-Object Status -eq Running

